# Facebook Login Api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, facebook-login

am trying to create facebook login api in my website .. 
i've tried javascript sdk but the same error always .. 
even i tried facebook example .. and the same error returned ..

and doesn't login ..

this error in chrome console :

```
GET http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/QjK2hWv6uak.js?version=41 404 (Not Found)
```

i don't know whats the problem ..

here is ms code ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>


<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses
  the JavaScript SDK to present a graphical Login button that triggers
  the FB.login() function when clicked.
-->
<div id="fb-root">
</div>
<script>

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'MyApiID',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.1' // use version 2.1
  });
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
      // login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they 
      // have logged in to the app.
      var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
      var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
      consol.log(accessToken);

      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // In this case, the person is logged into Facebook, but not into the app, so we call
      // FB.login() to prompt them to do so. 
      // In real-life usage, you wouldn't want to immediately prompt someone to login 
      // like this, for two reasons:
      // (1) JavaScript created popup windows are blocked by most browsers unless they 
      // result from direct interaction from people using the app (such as a mouse click)
      // (2) it is a bad experience to be continually prompted to login upon page load.
      FB.login();
    } else {
      // In this case, the person is not logged into Facebook, so we call the login() 
      // function to prompt them to do so. Note that at this stage there is no indication
      // of whether they are logged into the app. If they aren't then they'll see the Login
      // dialog right after they log in to Facebook. 
      // The same caveats as above apply to the FB.login() call here.
      FB.login();
    }
  });
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }
</script>
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

i use this

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
```

and tried this

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/debug.js";
```

and tried this

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/sdk.js";
```

and always the same error without login ..

Answer (score 0):

Enter your appId in js.src

js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#**xfbml=1&appId=*****************&version=v2.0";

Comment: same problem, but also this error appear ..( FB.init has already been called - this could indicate a problem )